# If val variables are immutable how I was able to change its value?

Tags: kotlin

```
class Mobile(val company: String= "unknown", var model: String ="unknown") {
fun call(mobile: Mobile) = "Calling with ${mobile.model} from the company ${mobile.company}"
}

fun main()
{
    val mobile = Mobile("Samsung", "S10")
}
```

In the previous code: How kotlin compiler was able to change the variable company although it was declared as 'val'?

Comment: Where do you think you changed the value? I think you're confused about the default value declaration. `val company: String= "unknown"` declares a _default_ value to be used if no value is passed for this field (e.g. if you used `Mobile()` or `Mobile(model = "S10")`). However, in `Mobile("Samsung", "S10")` you're explicitly specifying a value for both `company` and `model`, so the default is not applied.

Comment: is this also the same when declaring functions with arguments or it is just for the constructor?

Comment: It works the same for functions. I recommend that you familiarize yourself with the Kotlin basics by reading its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those values passed in the Mobile class are just default values as part of the declaration of the constructor of your Mobile class, those will be used if you don't provide any when instantiating the class. But since in you main you are instantiating the class with company="Samsung" and model="S10" those values are used instead of the defaults.

Keep in mind that `class Mobile(val company: String= "unknown", var model: String ="unknown")` is just a declaration so `company` and `model` are not really initialised until you call the constructor